# force removeAttribute() from org.w3c.dom.Element

Tags: java, xml, dom, svg, batik

I am trying to remove an attributs from an org.w3c.dom.Element.
When using removeAttribute the attribut-name (with an default value) is still contained in the resulting XML (in this case a SVG file).
In the JavaDoc I found the following explanation:

> If a default value for the removed attribute is defined in the DTD, a new attribute immediately appears with the default value as well as the corresponding namespace URI, local name, and prefix when applicable.

How can I avoid this behaviour? I can not change the DTD. I just want to get rid of this attribut.

Edit:
T.J. Crowder asked me for a minimal example.

```
import org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SAXSVGDocumentFactory;
import org.apache.batik.util.XMLResourceDescriptor;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class MinimalExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
        SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
        Document doc = f.createDocument("batik.svg");
        Element svg = doc.getDocumentElement();

        svg.removeAttribute("contentStyleType");

        System.out.println(getXML(doc));
    }
    public static String getXML(Document doc) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFact.newDocumentBuilder();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        //transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        System.out.println("XML IN String format is: \n" + writer.toString());
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help people answer if you provided a [mcve] of the problem. But it sounds like you can't do what you want to do, because of the default in the DTD.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated the question with an example code.